# How to delete the contents of the table in oracle using UPDATE command?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to delete the contents of the entire table using UPDATE command please help me out with this...
I tried using SET clause and tried to set all the fields to NULL value..But its not Working please tell Me

Comment: share the update command and error with it??

Comment: Why do you want to delete using update?

Comment: Do you mean you set a value to NULL but it's still populated?  Perhaps there's a trigger changing values behind the scenes.  Or if you want to UPDATE and DELETE at the same time that's possible with the MERGE syntax.

Comment: can you please guide me with that syntax with an example....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete rows using UPDATE command. You can empty them - set NULLs to all columns, but rows remains in the table. Use

```
DELETE your_table;
```

all rows in `your_table` will be deleted.

Comment: yes..i tried with the delete and drop and truncate command too...but i need it with "UPDATE" command...please guide me..

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

if you are so sure you are not going to need this data anymore. [faster]

> truncate table  [table_name];

This one will generate redo and you could rescue data with -flashback to time- or -flashback table to beofre drop-

> delete [table_name];

Regards.